# Iterating with for through a list isn't starting at the index

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of primes that I am importing from a text file. When I iterate through the list with for, it starts at the third member, but when I use a while loop this problem doesn't occur. My code so far is this:

```
with open("primes.txt", "r") as f:
    primes = list(f)

primes = [int(i) for i in primes]

z = 0

while z < 10:              #here it starts printing "2,3,5,7,11,..."
    print(primes[z])
    z += 1

for x in primes:           #here it starts printing "5,7,11,..."
    print(primes[x])
```

I want to know why this happens, if there's a problem when creating the list or if there's any way to fix it.

Comment: Because you've got `print(primes[x])` in your loop, instead of `print(x)`.  You're printing out the second prime, the third prime, the fifth prime, the seventh prime.  I bet you're not really printing out 11, but skipping to 13.

Comment: Such a simple mistake. Thanks for helping out a noob like me! (and you were right, it skipped to 13)

Comment: An easy mistake to make, especially since you've got `print(primes[z]))` in the first loop.  Sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Here you iterate over z, which starts at 0, so its prints the primes correctly, since the first prime (primes[0]) is 2

```
while z < 10:              #here it starts printing "2,3,5,7,11,..."
print(primes[z])
z += 1
```

In the second Block you iterate over the actual prime numbers, so the first print contains primes[2]. So it starts with the 3rd prime number.

```
for x in primes:           #here it starts printing "5,7,11,..."
print(primes[x])
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second loop, you need to say `print(x)` rather than `print(primes[x])`.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('primes.txt', 'r') as f:
# size_to_read = 100
f_content = f.readlines()
print(f_content)
primes = [int(i) for i in f_content]
# f.close()
for prime in primes:
    print(prime)
f.close()
```

There exists a method in python called .readlines() that you can apply on file objects and it returns a list for you of all lines in your text file.  Happy to help!